# HTML5 input pattern for Irish Vat Number

Tags: regex, html

The Irish VAT number format is:

Ireland VAT Seven digits and one letter or Six digits and two letters

What would the HTML5 input pattern for this be?
I have tried this:

```
(([0-9]{6}[A-Fa-f]{2})|([0-9]{7}[A-Fa-f]{1}))
```

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, note that all the parenthesis and the quantifier `{1}` are useless. Are you sure that the letters are limited to A-F and not A-Z?

Comment: Why do you think your pattern is wrong?

Comment: After a [quick search](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/vat-eu-country-codes-vat-numbers-and-vat-in-other-languages), it seems that Irish VAT numbers can be in three different formats: 1234567X, 1X23456X, 1234567XX *(There is no format starting with 6 digits)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Casimir is right, you may use the following:

```
\d[a-fA-F\d]\d{4}[a-fA-F\d][a-fA-F]
```

`\d` is for digits. You don't need the parenthesis. If you don't want to support the 1X23456X case, then you should replace the RegEX for this one:

```
\d{6}[a-fA-F\d][a-fA-F]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I used the following (as I think a-z is valid) 

"\d[a-zA-Z\d]\d{4}[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z]"